# How to find the index of maximum element in ojalgo?

Tags: java, sparse-matrix, ojalgo

How to find the index of maximum element in ojalgo?

To find maximum I can use `double res = mat.aggregateAll(Aggregator.MAXIMUM);`, but how to find the maximum's indices?

PS: the mat is type of `SparseStore<Double>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what type `mat` is?

There is a method `indexOfLargest()` defined in the `Access1D.Aggregatable` interface – implemented by a lot of different classes. But, this corresponds to `Aggregator.LARGEST` rather than `Aggregator.MAXIMUM`.

Since you tagged the question with *sparse-matrix* I assume the type is `SparseStore`, and that could be problematic, using `indexOfLargest()`, as I believe its implementation of that method does not exploit sparsity. (It's just some inherited default method that would perform terribly on a sparse matrix.)

You can, quite efficiently, iterate over all nonzero elements in a `SparseStore`:

```
    for (ElementView2D<N, ?> nz : mat.nonzeros()) {
        nz.row();
        nz.column();
        nz.index();
        nz.doubleValue();
    }
```